# System.FinalException: Testing has not started

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
private static testMethod void test() {
    Exception ee = null; 
    try{
        utilclass.disableAll(UserInfo.getUserId());
        Test.startTest();

        initTestData();

        ABCclass abc = new ABCclass();
        Object[] data = abc.abcclassmethod(searchFields, '', null, 0, 0);

        System.assert(data.size() > 0, 'No data available');
        data.clear();

    } catch(Exception e){
        ee = e;
    } finally {
        Test.stopTest();
        utilclass.enableAll(UserInfo.getUserId());
        if(ee != null){
            throw ee;
        }
    } 
}
```

While executing I am getting the below error:

> System.FinalException: Testing has not started

Comment: You're using the method `Test.stopTest();`. It must be precede by a call of `Test.startTest();`

Comment: long story short -- exception appeared in utilclass.disableAll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is possible, when `Test.startTest();` is not executed, when `utilclass.disableAll(UserInfo.getUserId());` will throw any exception, so you have this error. To fix it enclose testing method with `Test.startTest();` `Test.stoptest()`, so remove stop test from finally block

```
private static testMethod void test() {
    Exception ee = null; 
    try{
        utilclass.disableAll(UserInfo.getUserId());

        Test.startTest();
            initTestData();
        Test.stopTest();

        ABCclass abc = new ABCclass();
        Object[] data = abc.abcclassmethod(searchFields, '', null, 0, 0);

        System.assert(data.size() > 0, 'No data available');
        data.clear();

    } catch(Exception e){
        ee = e;
    } finally {
        utilclass.enableAll(UserInfo.getUserId());
        if(ee != null){
            throw ee;
        }
    } 
}
```